# Clear previously printed message with fprintf

Tags: matlab, printf

While executing a script, I have used

```
msg='Please wait...';
a=fprintf('%6s\n',msg);
fprintf('\n');
```

before the results get displayed. However after the results disclosure on the screen "Please wait..." is still appearing although I used

```
clear a
```

Thus, is there a way of turning off in the code

```
fprintf()
```

Comment: Yes, comment it out, simply delete it, put it in a verbosity-switched `if` statement etc

Comment: comment it out will prevent the `Please wait...` to be displayed before the results. I'd like it to be turned `on` let's say in `line 1` and then `off` in `line 20` for instance.

Comment: The use `fprintf` in line 1 and not in line 20 I guess. I do not get what you want here

Comment: just showing `Please wait...` since my results (simulations) takes minutes, but once the calculations are done and printed out in the screen, then logically `turn off` `Please wait` since there is no more reason to wait for any results.

Comment: You can't delete a specific line of the console. And it will be useless. So don't print something in the console but use `waitbar` instead

Comment: @obchardon: nice feedback with `waitbar`. Unfortunately it does not allow a varying argument to see the bar progressing (in a dynamic way). For instance it would have been _perfect_ if once could set for instance `h = waitbar([0.1:0.05:0.9999],'Please wait');` Good way around anyway. Thanks again.

Comment: @obchardon:Ps: _was not an intention to neither  `delete` or `comment` specic line of code but find a way of `turning off` a particular command `fprintf()`_. Although `waitbar` is an interesting substitute I am still be curious to see whether or not such task/command possible/available in MATLAB. cheers.

Answer (score 0):

`Clear a:` the clear function delete the selected variable from the memory. To clear the console you have to use `clc`.

But you can also comment or delete the line where fprintf is called.

Comment: I've been aware of `clc`, however it cleans everything from the console. in my case I'd just like to `turn off ` `frintf()` which will be specific to a particular message printed out.

Answer (score 0):

As already stated you have to use `clc` to clear the command window.

You can also erase just the last characters by inserting multiple backspaces. For instance:

```
fprintf(repmat(char(8), [1 numel(msg)]));
```

Comment: @does not work and furthermore does not match my expectations. As explained to Adrian earlier, I am looking for a way of `turning on `fprintf()` in `line1` = `Please wait...` (just before my results are printed) and `turn it off` (delete `Please wait`) as soon my results are printed, let's say in `line 20`.

Comment: Ah, I get it. No idea how to do that, but I'd just add another `fprintf('Done!')` instead of trying to remove the previous line.

Comment: Cheers. Thanks for the way around, but I am afraid to keep both `Please wait...` and `Done!`. As a _perfectionist_, I was looking for a _nicer/better_ approach with `turn a message on/off`. I was also curious to know _how far_ MATLAB potentialities could go with commands I am not aware off.

Comment: `char(10)` is not backspace but newline; backspace is ASCII 8. Moreover, there is a parenthesis missing in your code. Better to try your code before posting!

Comment: @owner Sorry but your question was rather unclear, at least to me.

Comment: @Donda I've corected the typos, thanks for signaling. Indeed I'll try to stop posting from my phone from now on, since I cannot check.